# How to run a selected set of unit tests in Eclipse with one mouseclick?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I want to create a launcher/run configuration which runs only the JUnit tests in a selected set of test classes or selected set of packages. Now it looks like I'll have to create separate run configurations for each of my packages containing the tests I want to run. I also have a recollection of this working in older versions of Eclipse.

And yes, I know: The tests should be organized so that I wouldn't have this problem but reorganizing source folders right now is not an option.

I'm using Eclipse 3.4.2.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a JUnit test suite like this :

[image: JUnit Test Suite]

Comment: Thanks, should have been quite obvious :) I just created a test suite by hand not remembering that it shouldn't be done by extending the TestSuite-class. And of course couldn't run it :-) This solution will do, although it's not optimal: I'll have to remember to add all Test-classes which I create to the suite which is a bit redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a test suite for the selected tests.

I would put them in a separate source folder, as otherwise tests will be run multiple times, once for the original test and once for each suite it is in.

Comment: Hod do I run a JUnit test suite in Eclipse?

Yes, organizing the source folders in a sane way should be done, but it would be a massive amount of work for this project (the build files are a royal mess) and we can't afford that right now.

Answer (score 1):

> Hod do I run a JUnit test suite in
>   Eclipse? Yes, organizing the source
>   folders in a sane way should be done,
>   but it would be a massive amount of
>   work for this project (the build files
>   are a royal mess) and we can't afford
>   that right now.

*auramo*

You choose your TestSuite and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd> or do `Run -> Run As -> JUnit Test`.